# Norm of integral operator in $L_1[a, b]$, $F(f) = \int_a^b K(t,x) f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider $$F(f) = \int_a^b K(t,x) f(t)dt$$ which maps $L_1[a,b]$ to $L_1[a,b]$.

We want to find it's norm. Using Hölder inequality we can estimate it like: $$\|F\| \le \sup_{\|f\|_{L_1} = 1}\int_a^b \int_a^b |K(x,t) f(t)|dt \le \int_a^b \int_a^b|K(t,x)|dtdx$$

But it's quite complicated to determine the sequence, on which the norm occurs. We need a function, which integral norm on $[a,b]$ is unit and which is equal to $\operatorname{sign}(K(t,))$. Maybe there should be another answer?

Comment: your last inequality, I guess should have a sup in $t$ instead

Comment: Try to  solve first the analogous problem of an operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the $\ell^1$ norm. For your problem, approximate $K$ with a linear combination of characteristic functions of rectangles.

Comment: @CalvinKhor you mean $\sup_{t} \|K(t,x)\|$?

Comment: @openspace well that’s what comes out of Holder’s